# Is it possible to undo a paste on the Windows comandline?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, console

I like to **undo** my paste on the Windows command line  (e.g. PowerShell)

For example:

1. Type `git checkout`
2. Paste the clipboard which has the text `test` - we have now `git checkout test` (I use right click paste)
3. Desired: Undo the paste, so we have again `git checkout`

Unfortunately pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> removes the whole line! (so we have  instead of `git checkout`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Powershell you can simply use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> but on regular cmd shell it will not work...

Comment: That removes only 1 character as the time - it's behaves the same as 'backspace'?

Comment: if you do CTRL+V and not mouse paste, it will remove it all

Comment: Not on my system... :'(  (tested it with CTRL+V also)

Comment: works in my system PS5.1, try the PowerShell ISE maybe

Comment: I see that indeed CTRL+V  and  CTRL+Z  works on powershell console. I'm using ConEnu, haven't expected a difference.

Comment: But I always use "right click paste", so really looking for a solution for that one